# Robolectric NoClassDefFoundError with external library

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric

all my project activities inherits from a CustomActivity that is a external library i've created to help me with common usage things.

The problem is when i try to test that activity with robolectric i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/androidcore/activity/CustomActivity
```

Any ideas? Should i shadow it? Should i put a reference into some Robolectric Config?

Here is my app build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.boozeprice"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

    compile project(':androidcore')
    compile project(':persistencecore')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

EDIT, Adding extra info:

My gradle version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
public class IntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void testActivity() {
        Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        TextView txt = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
        String result = txt.getText().toString();
        assertThat(result, equalTo("Test"));
    }
}
```

My CustomRunner:

```
 public class CustomRobolectricRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public CustomRobolectricRunner(Class<?> testClass)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String path = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";

        // android studio has a different execution root for tests than pure gradle
        // so we avoid here manual effort to get them running inside android studio
        if (!new File(path).exists()) {
            path = "app/" + path;
        }

        config = overwriteConfig(config, "manifest", path);
        return super.getAppManifest(config);
    }

    protected Config.Implementation overwriteConfig(
            Config config, String key, String value) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(key, value);
        return new Config.Implementation(config,
                Config.Implementation.fromProperties(properties));
    }

    @Override
    protected SdkConfig pickSdkVersion(
            AndroidManifest appManifest, Config config) {
        // current Robolectric supports not the latest android SDK version
        // so we must downgrade to simulate the latest supported version.
        config = overwriteConfig(config, "emulateSdk", "18");
        return super.pickSdkVersion(appManifest, config);
    }
}
```

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomActivity
```

Custom Activity:

```
public abstract class CustomActivity extends Activity
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What android gradle plugin version do you use?

Comment: Can you share your test class?

Comment: Just added the extra info, thank you.

Comment: Ok, Can you share your custom runner code? I would assume it can not find your manifest file

Comment: Added the custom runner, i get this message: WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/androidcore/activity/CustomActivity

I dont have any messages about the manifest not being found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The base issue is that robolectric don't know you library resources. But this can be fixed ...

**Option 1:** update robolectric to 3.0-rc2

Delete your custom runner. There is a new class RobolectricGradleTestRunner which fix resource loading for library dependencies

**Option 2:** use workaround from RobolectricGradleTestRunner

Delete all code from your custom robolectric runner and add

```
public CustomRobolectricRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
    String buildVariant = (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty() ? "" : BuildConfig.FLAVOR+ "/") + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
    String intermediatesPath = getClass().getResource("").toString().replace("file:", "");
    System.out.println(intermediatesPath);
    intermediatesPath = intermediatesPath.substring(0, intermediatesPath.indexOf("/classes"));

    System.setProperty("android.package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    System.setProperty("android.manifest", intermediatesPath + "/manifests/full/" + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
    System.setProperty("android.resources", intermediatesPath + "/res/" + buildVariant);
    System.setProperty("android.assets", intermediatesPath + "/assets/" + buildVariant);
}
```

For some examples visit:

- https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples
- https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template
- https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Comment: I have updated to robolectric 3.0-rc2 and the error continues, any other sugestion?

Comment: I did what you said and now it cant find the manifest file and im getting this error: .FileNotFoundException (AndroidManifest) and Robolectric does not support API level 1

Comment: It appears that you cant have special characters on dir path, so i've changed and now i only got this error:

Resources$NotFoundException
ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve

Any idea? It is still about my custom acitivty androidcore.activity.CustomActivity.onCreate(CustomActivity.java:19)

Comment: Just updated to robolectric 3.0-rc2 and added a customrunner like this project uses: https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric